# Estoy tratando de generar un horario de clase mediante una consulta en MySQL

Tags: mysql

La consulta que estoy realizando en MySQL es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT CONCAT(hs.initime," - ",hs.endtime) AS Hora,
 CASE WHEN hs.DAY = 'Lunes' THEN hs.description ELSE '' END Lunes,
 CASE WHEN hs.DAY = 'Martes' THEN hs.description ELSE '' END Martes,
 CASE WHEN hs.DAY = 'Miercoles' THEN hs.description ELSE '' END Miercoles,
 CASE WHEN hs.DAY = 'Jueves' THEN hs.description ELSE '' END Jueves,
 CASE WHEN hs.DAY = 'Viernes' THEN hs.description ELSE '' END Viernes,
 CASE WHEN hs.DAY = 'Sabado' THEN hs.description ELSE '' END Sabado
 FROM horario hs
```

Comment: y cual es la duda? la pregunta no es clara

Comment: la duda ,,, quiero que me liste de forma ordenada segun los dias

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE horarios(
  id_horario int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  DAY varchar(15),
  initime time,
  endtime time,
  descripcion varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO horarios (DAY, initime, endtime, descripcion) VALUES
  ('Lunes','9:00','10:00','Matemáticas'),
  ('Lunes','10:00','11:00','Comunicación'),
  ('Martes','9:00','10:00','Java'),
  ('Martes','10:00','11:00','Python'),
  ('Miércoles','9:00','10:00','Matemáticas'),
  ('Miércoles','10:00','11:00','Comunicación'),
  ('Jueves','9:00','10:00','Java'),
  ('Jueves','10:00','11:00','Python');
```

Con tu consulta se obtendría un resultado así:

```
==============================================================================
|Hora      |Lunes     |Martes    |Miercoles |Jueves    |Viernes   |Sabado    |
==============================================================================
|09:00:00  |Matemática|          |          |          |          |          |
|-         |s         |          |          |          |          |          |
|10:00:00  |          |          |          |          |          |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|10:00:00  |Comunicaci|          |          |          |          |          |
|-         |ón        |          |          |          |          |          |
|11:00:00  |          |          |          |          |          |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|09:00:00  |          |Java      |          |          |          |          |
|-         |          |          |          |          |          |          |
|10:00:00  |          |          |          |          |          |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|10:00:00  |          |Python    |          |          |          |          |
|-         |          |          |          |          |          |          |
|11:00:00  |          |          |          |          |          |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|09:00:00  |          |          |Matemática|          |          |          |
|-         |          |          |s         |          |          |          |
|10:00:00  |          |          |          |          |          |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|10:00:00  |          |          |Comunicaci|          |          |          |
|-         |          |          |ón        |          |          |          |
|11:00:00  |          |          |          |          |          |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|09:00:00  |          |          |          |Java      |          |          |
|-         |          |          |          |          |          |          |
|10:00:00  |          |          |          |          |          |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|10:00:00  |          |          |          |Python    |          |          |
|-         |          |          |          |          |          |          |
|11:00:00  |          |          |          |          |          |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Para que, para la misma hora en diferentes días, se muestre una única línea, he optado por agrupar por horas generando una columna diferente para cada día:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT initime,endtime FROM horarios
  ) horas LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT initime,endtime,
      GROUP_CONCAT(descripcion) lunes
      FROM horarios WHERE DAY='Lunes'
      GROUP BY 1,2    
  ) lunes USING(initime,endtime) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT initime,endtime,
      GROUP_CONCAT(descripcion) martes
      FROM horarios WHERE DAY='Martes'
      GROUP BY 1,2    
  ) martes USING(initime,endtime) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT initime,endtime,
      GROUP_CONCAT(descripcion) miercoles
      FROM horarios WHERE DAY='Miércoles'
      GROUP BY 1,2    
  ) miercoles USING(initime,endtime) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT initime,endtime,
      GROUP_CONCAT(descripcion) jueves
      FROM horarios WHERE DAY='Jueves'
      GROUP BY 1,2    
  ) jueves USING(initime,endtime) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT initime,endtime,
      GROUP_CONCAT(descripcion) viernes
      FROM horarios WHERE DAY='Viernes'
      GROUP BY 1,2    
  ) viernes USING(initime,endtime)
  ORDER BY horas.initime,horas.endtime;
```

Obtenemos este resultado:

> ```
> ==============================================================================
> |initime   |endtime   |lunes     |martes    |miercoles |jueves    |viernes   |
> ==============================================================================
> |09:00:00  |10:00:00  |Matemática|Java      |Matemática|Java      |null      |
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |10:00:00  |11:00:00  |Comunicaci|Python    |Comunicaci|Python    |null      |
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```